# Creating cross-browser background gradient s

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

maybe stupid question, but I need some help
I am creating a website, and I noticed that this code for background gradient

`background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(180, 180, 180, 0)), to(#E7E7E7));`
works only in Google chrome, in other browser it doesn't look like I want, so anyone has some suggestions?

[Check demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rqq0Lws/)

Comment: Could u write me some example code of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard syntax is

```css
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(180, 180, 180, 0), #E7E7E7);
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(180, 180, 180, 0), #E7E7E7);
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Cross-browser_gradients), a cross-browser code would be

```css
background-color: #E7E7E7; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(180, 180, 180, 0), #E7E7E7); /* For Chrome 25 and Safari 6, iOS 6.1, Android 4.3 */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(180, 180, 180, 0), #E7E7E7); /* For Firefox (3.6 to 15) */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(180, 180, 180, 0), #E7E7E7); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(180, 180, 180, 0), #E7E7E7); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need prefixes for all browsers.

For this example use:

```
background: #b4b400; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b4b400 0%, #e7e7e7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b4b400), color-stop(100%,#e7e7e7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b4b400 0%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b4b400 0%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b4b400 0%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b4b400 0%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4b400', endColorstr='#e7e7e7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

You can create your gradient with all prefixes on same generator, for example:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor